# How to keep form controls but remove layout panel?

Tags: winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I implemented an About Box and added some hyperlinks:

[image: AboutBox]

I don't like the Layout Panel concept. How can I keep the controls without the layout panel and retain the form functionality (ie. it reads values from assembly resources)?

Comment: The functionality doesn't have anything to do with the layout. Reorder the layout in any order which you prefer.

Comment: @RezaAghaei This layout panel is a new concept to me. If our image on the left is a specific size then how do we ensure that we show it to that size?

Comment: `PictureBox` has `Size` and `ImageSizeMode`. Play with those properties to see how the combination of them will work.

Comment: I probably keep the `TableLayoutPanel` and just change the height percentage of the rows [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hng7.png).